# Unable to access network on ubuntu installed via wubi

Tags: networking, grub2, wubi, internet, windows-xp

I've installed ubuntu via wubi for windows (xp). However I'm unable to access internet via ubuntu whereas it works perfectly inwindows xp. Also I'm unable to access the grub menu  when I press shift after selecting ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about wubi but for network log into Ubuntu, open terminal press ctrl+alt+t, and issue `sudo lshw -c network` and `ifconfig -a` and `nm-tool` commands and post results here

Comment: ok thanks for the prompt reply, it'll take a while as I'm downloading wubi afresh possibly 30 minutes but I'l do just that

Comment: thanks, I was able to access shared and internet after configuring my network settings afresh on ubuntu, I'd left out the DNS settings as soon as I filled that in I was connected!